# Insert int and string values into a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list like this:

```
[4000, 5000, 6000, 'No price', 0, 'No price']
```

and I want to iterate on the list and insert values into a mysql table.
I define int value for the table and as a result,it cannot insert 'No price' into the table because of string type.I want to insert None value instead of string value. How can I solve this problem? This is my code:

```
for price, operation in zip(cost_list,mile_list):
    add_cars = "INSERT INTO car_list(price, operation) VALUES(%s, %s)"
    val = (price, operation)
    cursor.execute(add_cars, val)
```

Comment: Please show the code you are having trouble with.  Also, since it is impossible to put a string into an int field, what would you want to go in (if anything) in its place?

Comment: Please include all the relevant code. Double check that you didn't make an error in your IDE as there is one here `0',`

Comment: Create the int field nullable and put a null in it - or make a "default" value that signifies no price - f.e. `-1`

Comment: What's the difference between `no price` and `price = 0`? Why not just use `0` instead?

Comment: @Barmar because price of some products are 0 and some have no price because of missing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the variable is an integer, and replace it with a default value if not.

```
add_cars = "INSERT INTO car_list(price, operation) VALUES(%s, %s)"
for price, operation in zip(cost_list,mile_list):
    if not isinstance(price, int):
        price = None
    val = (price, operation)
    cursor.execute(add_cars, val)
```

Comment: I must insert None or Null value in the cell that has no price

Comment: Then use `None` as the default value.